# 'be used to' as a passive form to express a purpose

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive-vs-gerund

I know *be used to* (used not as a tense form) means *be accustomed to*. I wonder if I can use it (but this time as a passive form of *use*) to express a purpose. For example,

> The keyboard is **used to** type words.

I also know that as an alternative I can say,

> The keyboard is **used for** typing words.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct or should I avoid it for some reason? Is it perfect English or does it sounds off to native ears?

Comment: When used to mean accustomed, "used" is an **adjective**. But in your examples, it is a **verb** meaning roughly "employed". "Used to type words" is a predicative complement of "be" with "keyboard" as predicand. Note that tt's only the complement of "used", i.e. "to type words" that has a purposive meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both make sense to me as a native English speaker, although the usage in

> "The keyboard is **used to** type words."

is not equivalent to

> "I don't mind the rain, I'm **used to** it."

for example.

For the usage here to be equivalent, I think we'd have to be anthropomorphising the keyboard and saying something like:

> "The keyboard is used to having words typed on it"

or

> "The keyboard is used to being used for typing words" or similar.

When employing "used to" to express familiarity, it's usually (in the UK at least) pronounced slightly differently too - the "used" rhymes with "boost" when being used to express being accustomed to something, but rhymes with "cruised" when being used to express using something as a tool for example.

Comment: +1 thank you so much. i wish i could give you two upvotes :)